# How can I add second join which calculates an AVG to this query?

Tags: mysql, database, join

I have a query which joins two tables and counts the total in a second table by song ID.

How can I modify this query to include an average of the column 'ratings' in a **third** table ($sTable3) again, with the same song id.

```
    $sQuery = "
        SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS ".str_replace(" , ", " ", implode(", ", $aColumns))."

    FROM $sTable b 
    LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT COUNT(*) AS projects_count, a.songs_id

   FROM $sTable2 a
   GROUP BY a.songs_id
) bb ON bb.songs_id = b.songsID


        $sWhere
        $sOrder
        $sLimit
    ";
```

This is all put into a JSON array and I would like to return this 'average' under a new column 'ratings'.

To summarize (as i'm aware I may not be articulating this well):-

I have three tables $sTable, $sTable2, $sTable3. All three share a songID column.  My current query joins the first two and returns all results exactly as I want.  However I need to also retrieve data related to the songID from the 'rating' column of $sTable3.

Comment: If it's a question about a SQL query, you should only show the SQL query, not your mashup of PHP and MySQL that we need to decode to work out the question.

Comment: My Apologies. I did not intend to make this difficult for anyone and wasn't aware I was doing so.

Comment: That's fine, never too late to edit :)  The main problem is that we can't really see what Table1, Table2 or Table3 actually contain, so don't know how they relate, which affects the joins and stuff.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Had to guess a lot of your problem, as you don't reveal much about the setup, just some (inexplicably cryptically-named) variables.

```
SELECT songs.title, AVG(ratings.rating), COUNT(something.songs_id)
FROM songs
LEFT JOIN something ON (songs.songs_id=something.songsID)
LEFT JOIN ratings ON (songs.songs_id=ratings.songsID)
GROUP BY songs.title
```

Comment: You sir are a life saver.  Thank you... stupidly simple answer too.  Unfortunately i'm a UI/front end engineer who's been lumped with some back end modifications with little to no DB knowledge.  You've been a great help, thank you.